# WordPress inserting source code into post giving an undesirable result

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am a WordPress beginner. I want to insert css code into an article but i am getting a too big lines size. 
[image]

I wrote this in wordpress :

```
[sourcecode language="css"]
#button{
      font-weight: bold;
      border: 2px solid #fff;
}

[/sourcecode]
```

I want something like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress's source code generator uses tables for its layout, so if you have any CSS that affects arbitrary table elements then it will affect the layout of your source code too.